# Solution for passing an array rather than a string to a function to upload files (node.js)

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, file-upload, cloudinary

*Updated the original question to try simplify the context:*

I want to apply the values in an array as the first argument of a function for each value in the array.

E.g. So for `arg1` in foo:

```
foo(arg1, arg2, arg3) 

var myArray = [ 'image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg',  'image3.jpg' ]
```

Apply each image as the first argument:

```
foo(image1.jpg, arg2, arg3) 

foo(image2.jpg, arg2, arg3) 

foo(image3.jpg, arg2, arg3)
```

I was thinking the .apply method might be a way to do this but not been able to get this to work. Would a for loop be needed?

For example:

```
myFunction.apply(this, myArray)

myFunction = foo(this, arg2, arg3)
```

In context:

```
var oneImageArray = ['lake.jpg', 'pizza.jpg'];

myFunction.apply(this, oneImageArray);

cloudinary.uploader.upload(
    this, {folder: "test/name", use_filename: true, unique_filename: false , tags: 'basic_sample'},function(err,image){
  console.log();
  if (err){ console.warn(err);}
  console.log("* "+image.public_id);
  console.log("* "+image.url);
  waitForAllUploads("test",err,image);
});
```

*Original question:*

I want to pass an array of files to cloudinary’s upload function so I can upload a batch of images (rather than a single image which works fine).

> The Cloudinary upload method performs an authenticated upload API call
>   over HTTPS while sending the image file:

```
cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(file, options, callback);
```

From the [forum](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/202520662-How-can-I-bulk-upload-my-images-) it suggests I can

> “migrate your existing images to Cloudinary, write a short script that
>   traverses your images and upload them one-by-one using Cloudinary's
>   upload API.”

So I'm trying to achieve this by using `fs-readdir-recursive` to obtain an array of all the files in a specified folder.

The process works when a single image is assigned as the first argument of the upload function. 
I thought I might be able to create a variable that passes the array returned by fs-readdir but the following errors

So I guess my question is why does the following not work and is there a viable alternate solution for automating the process for a batch of files?

```
    var dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.load();
var fs = require('fs');
var cloudinary = require('cloudinary').v2;
var uploads = {};

var read = require('fs-readdir-recursive');

var allMyImages = read("src/images");

cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: 'myName',
  api_key: 'myKey',
  api_secret: 'mySecret'
});

cloudinary.uploader.upload(
    allMyImages, {folder: "test/name", use_filename: true, unique_filename: false , tags: 'basic_sample'},function(err,image){
  console.log();
  if (err){ console.warn(err);}
  console.log("* "+image.public_id);
  console.log("* "+image.url);
  waitForAllUploads("test",err,image);
});

 function waitForAllUploads(id,err,image){
   uploads[id] = image;
   var ids = Object.keys(uploads);
   if (ids.length==6){
     console.log();
     console.log ('**  uploaded all files ('+ids.join(',')+') to cloudinary');
     performTransformations();
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says in the documentation, you can upload the images one-by-one. 
A simple for-loop over your images array should work.

```
for(var i = 0; i < allMyImages.length;i++){
   cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(allMyImages[i], options, callback);
 }
```

Good luck!

Comment: That works perfectly - thank you. Just to add when using the for loop I realised I also hadn't added the image path I was using to prefix the first argument i.e. ('src/images/' + imagesInFolder[i], options, callback). thanks again.